# Delta function that obeys inverse square law outside its (-1; 1) range and has no 1/0 infinity

Tags: inverse, infinity

Does anybody know if such function exists? As I understand it, the function $$\frac{1}{x^2}$$ itself could be used as a delta function if it had no 1/0 infinity.

That is why I'm in a search of an "inverse square law" delta function that has maybe a shape like parabola in the range (-1; 1). Knowing its integral expression would be useful, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "delta function"?

Comment: A function which is symmetrical around its argument 0 and its value falls with some pace on both sides. E.g. Gaussian function is a good example of delta function.

Comment: Why do you need such a function? It seems very specific so it would be great if you could explain a little more about the use.

Comment: Gravity modeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Cauchy distribution $p(x,\sigma)$ fits the bill:
$$ p(x,\sigma) = \frac{\sigma/\pi}{\sigma^2+x^2} = 
   \frac{1/(\pi\,\sigma)}{1+(x/\sigma)^2} \qquad \mbox{with} \quad \sigma > 0$$
Where:
$$\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0}\, p(x,\sigma) = \delta(x)$$
Check that $\,p(x)\,$ is normed (: substitute $t=x/\sigma$):
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1/(\pi\,\sigma)}{1+(x/\sigma)^2}\,dx =
   \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^2} =
   \frac{1}{\pi} \left[\, \arctan(t)\, \right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = \pi/\pi = 1
$$
And:
$$  \lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty} \frac{\sigma/\pi}{\sigma^2+x^2} = 0 \qquad ; \qquad
  \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\sigma/\pi}{\sigma^2+x^2} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ll} \infty & \mbox{if} \quad x = 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{if} \quad x \ne 0
  \end{array}  \right.$$

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic, thank you!