# Singular linear systems of ODEs

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, eigenfunctions, singularity

A classical problem in quantum mechanics involving the Dirac Delta function is given by
$$
y''+(\delta(x)-\lambda^2)y=0.
$$ 
Then, to find ''bound states'', you solve on the right and find the converging solution as $x\rightarrow \infty$, then solve on the left similarly. Assume continuity of the solution $y$. The jump condition on $y'$ is found by integrating from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$ and take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. The only value of $\lambda$ giving a bound state is then found to be $1/2$.

In the literature, there are a lot of results concerning more complicated singular Schrödinger eigenvalue problems. More generally, I am looking at linear systems of ODEs with singular coefficients such as the coefficient in the example given above.

The problem given above can simply be thought of as the limit of smooth systems where you would replace the Dirac function by a parameter dependent function, which converges to the Dirac function when the parameter goes to zero. So, one would think that the eigenvector goes to the eigenvector given above as the parameter goes to zero.

My question is this: Are there results, known examples, or references in the literature dealing with singular systems which have solutions, eigenvectors, or behaviors, which strictly appear in the singular limit and which are not obtained by taking the limit of smooth systems. In other words, I would like to know if there is something more to those systems involving Dirac functions than being the limit of smooth systems.

Comment: Do you realize that the dirac function is... not a function an is normally defined as a limit? Having said that, do you have any other specific examples which you would like to solve? Please write them explicitly in the question.

Comment: I think the answer to your questions is __no__. The reason is that, in real world mathematics - physics in your case - [any real valued function is somehow continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830199/is-any-real-valued-function-in-physics-somehow-continuous)

Comment: Crossposted from https://mathoverflow.net/q/211701/13917

Answer (score 0):

The standard theory you seem to be looking for is that of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). This theory was designed to give a rigorous framework for defining and dealing with diracs and other objects of interest (in Physics and elsewhere).

In particular, there is a notion of a Dirac distribution (not function) and you would usually look for a weak solution to your equation.